# Are there any ready to use gallery libraries to layout images not in gridview?

Tags: android, layout, image-gallery

I want to show my image gallery in more nice way than a grid view or list view.
Please have look at this screen:
[image]

There are [some algorithms](http://blog.vjeux.com/2012/image/image-layout-algorithm-lightbox-android.html) for doing this.

Is there an **existing library** which I could reuse for displaying such gallery?

Note the following:

1. My images are in my sqlite table, the amount of images is fixed
2. In table I have only urls for each image
3. I do not have images (and their sizes) in advance, so I would prefer to download them in lazy way (as much as possible)

Comment: http://www.androidviews.net/2013/01/pinterest-like-adapterview/. looking foe this?